# My query needs what kind of index?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 1
FROM ( SELECT count(*) AS num_week,
              ifnull(sum(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1  day))),0)  as num_day,
              ifnull(sum(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1  hour))),0) as num_hour,
              ifnull(sum(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 minute))),0) as num_1min
        FROM activate_account
       WHERE user_id   = ?  
         AND date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK))
      ) a 
WHERE num_week < 12 AND num_day < 6 AND num_hour < 4 AND num_1min < 1;
```

Well what index(es) query above needs? Either a single column or a multiple columns index? Here possible cases:

- `activate_account(user_id, date_time)`
- `activate_account(date_time, user_id)`
- `activate_account(date_time)`
- `activate_account(user_id)`

Ok which one is the best choose for that query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best index for your query is on `activate_account(user_id, date_time)`.  This satisfies the `where` clause, with the column with the equality condition first and then the inequality.

You don't need a subquery.  This should be fine:

```
SELECT count(*) AS num_week,
       COALESCE(sum(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1  day))),0)  as num_day,
       COALESCE(sum(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1  hour))),0) as num_hour,
       COALESCE(sum(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 minute))),0) as num_1min
FROM activate_account
WHERE user_id = ?  AND
      date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK))
HAVING num_week < 12 AND num_day < 6 AND num_hour < 4 AND num_1min < 1;
```

Comment: Ok good .. Just can you please tell me is there any different between that index you mentioned in this answer and this one `activate_account(date_time, user_id)` ?

Comment: Also your query isn't the same as mine. Your query returns multiple columns, but my query returns just one column contains either `1` or nothing.

Comment: OK, undo the `HAVING` part.

Comment: @MartinAJ . . . You can keep the subquery.  I wasn't sure if the intention was really to return "1" or if that was just short-hand.